# open gallery with only HD images

Tags: java, android

Is there any possibility to show only HD images while launching gallery using intent from app.

Below is the sample code snippet which I am using to open gallery with only images of jpeg,jpg and png. Please suggest how to show only HD images in gallery.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

String[] mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"};

intent.setType("*/*");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

Comment: What is a HD image?

Comment: `Please suggest how to show only HD images in gallery.` You mean: Please suggest how to show only HD images with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: For this you have to open the custom gallery in your project. same as Instagrams does when we click on gallery, If that works for you i can suggest further steps